# When array have more than one lack element then, how to pass array to data in line chart of chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, chart.js

I have created line chart using chart.js.But when array have more than one lack element then, how to pass array to data in line chart of chart.js.
When i am passing small number of element in array it work but for big number array element it not work.

```js
var num1: number;
var num2:number;
var x_Axes:number[]=[];
var y_Axes:number[]=[];
for(num1=0;num1<=60;num1++){
    xAxes.push(num1);
 }
for(num2=0;num2<=2000000;num2++){
   y_Axes.push(num2);
 }
 
 data: {
      labels: x_Axes,
      datasets: [
        {
          pointBorderColor: 'none',
          borderColor: "#D71F26",
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 0,
          data: y_Axes,
        }
```

You can see for labels i also use array and it work.but data it not work why i don't know.

> when page load browser not throw any error,it take long time to load and finally it show blank on graph.

Comment: Hi, first of all you should know whether all records should be displayed at the same time or is there any restrict like 100 records should be shown like that. if you have constrains you can use limit of records. if you don't have that you have to use delay/loading concept for ready your records.

Comment: By "one lack" I assume you mean [100,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh). That's a crazy number of data points that shouldn't be needed to create a meaningful chart (and might even be harmful by obscuring details). Look in to data decimation and the other options you have for [high performance charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#high-performance-line-charts).